# Homework: Java Binary Search tree. Editing a specific node

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I need help with a binary search tree. Here are the node and BST classes :

```
public class Node {
    private int key;
    private Node parent;
    private Node leftChild;
    private Node rightChild;

    public Node(int key, Node leftChild, Node rightChild) {
        this.setKey(key);
        this.setLeftChild(leftChild);
        this.setRightChild(rightChild);
    }

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setLeftChild(Node leftChild) {
        this.leftChild = leftChild;
    }

    public Node getLeftChild() {
        return leftChild;
    }

    public void setRightChild(Node rightChild) {
        this.rightChild = rightChild;
    }

    public Node getRightChild() {
        return rightChild;
    }
}

public class BinarySearchTree {

    private Node root;

    public void insert(int key) {
        insert(new Node(key, null, null));
    }

    public void insert(Node z) {

        Node y = null;
        Node x = root;

        while (x != null) {
            y = x;

            if (z.getKey() < x.getKey()) {
                x = x.getLeftChild();
            } else {
                x = x.getRightChild();
            }
        }

        z.setParent(y);

        if (y == null) {
            root = z;
        } else if (z.getKey() < y.getKey()) {
            y.setLeftChild(z);
        } else {
            y.setRightChild(z);
        }
    }

    public void preorderTraversal() {
        preorderTraversal(root);
    }

    public void preorderTraversal(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.getKey() + " ");
            preorderTraversal(node.getLeftChild());
            preorderTraversal(node.getRightChild());            
        }
    }

    public void inorderTraversal() {
        inorderTraversal(root);
    }

    private void inorderTraversal(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            inorderTraversal(node.getLeftChild());
            System.out.print(node.getKey() + " ");
            inorderTraversal(node.getRightChild());
        }
    }

    public void postorderTraversal() {
        postorderTraversal(root);
    }

    private void postorderTraversal(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            postorderTraversal(node.getLeftChild());
            postorderTraversal(node.getRightChild());
            System.out.print(node.getKey() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

(Taken from http://www.brilliantsheep.com/java-implementation-of-binary-search-tree-insert-and-traversal-methods/) This is a relatively simple implementation. However, I need to store extra information in each node The node must contain a candidate for an election and  the number of votes of the candidate. There has been lots of complaints about this assignment (and why BSTs must be used), but please let's not get into that.

I am numbering my candidates 1-20, and using this as the keys in my Binary search tree. My question is, using this code ( or a slightly modified version), how do I update a specific nodes information given its key?

eg. If the person votes for candidate 4), how do I update candidate 4's vote information?

I have seen some find methods, but I don't know on what node I am supposed to call it on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add two more properties to the `Node` class to store the extra information you need. So you Node class will look somewhat like this:

```
public class Node {

  private int key;
  private Node parent;
  private Node leftChild;
  private Node rightChild;

  public string candidateName;
  public int votes;

  // .. other properties and methods
}
```

When you get a vote for candidate 4, traverse your tree to find the Node with key 4, and do `node.votes++`

In pseudo-code, it would look like this:

```
Node node = root;

while (node.key != 4) {
  // implement your tree traversal algorithm here
}

// when you reach here, node is the candidate you were searching
// for, or null if not found

if (node != null) {
  node.votes++;
}
```

*Be sure to initialize `votes` to 0 in the Node constructor.*

Comment: Thanks a lot man, your method is perfect. A quick question, does root have a special meaning in java?

Comment: No, root here is mean to be the root node to your tree.